# Which IBAction referenced to which Button in Swift iOS development?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

New to iOS development with Swift code. A previous developer has created 2 buttons and used the `CTRL-drag-drop` technique to generate the `IBAction` methods. The same as the buttons, he created two labels and two `IBOutlet` variables. Let's say that he did not name each item, each outlet and each action appropriately, how do I find out which `IBAction` references to which button and which IBOutlet to which label in the Xcode environment?

Comment: Hover over the + icon in the gutter and it'll show you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the another way to check the widget action and outlet representation in xib.

Click on the IBOutlet/IBAction connected indication circle, It will show a popup of represented widget path and then click on it. It navigates you to the represented widget on xib.

[image]

Comment: That is even more easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this screenshot might help you

The button must be in your viewcontroller and you can check its property and you can check the IBAction for the same.

[image: Storyboard]

Let me know if you still have the issue finding IBAction

Comment: IBAction reference can be found under `Sent Eventa` in the connection inspector bar?